# R : Fast access to a given line of a big CSV file

Tags: r, performance, bigdata

My datasource are 2GB file composed of 3 columns : key1, key2, result. 
These files are composed of more than 10 millions of lines each. 
I am trying to access the i-th line of the j-th file as fast as possible from R, on a Windows system. Fread-ing the file is not an option as it takes more than 2 min, which is not possible in this use-case.

I have tried several methods but all failed so far :

**Methodology 1:** readlines, read.table or fread

```
readlines(file("myFile.csv", "r"),n=1, skip = M)

read.table("myFile.csv", skip=M, nrows=1)

fread("myFile.csv", skip=M, nrows=1)
```

*The problem with these methodologies is that when M tends to the end of the file, the access time is very long. I would be very interesed if a similar solution can be found*

**Methodology 2:** fst package

As suggested in the comment / answers section, the fst package works fine thanks to the `From` / `To` arguments, yet it requires the duplication of the CSVs under a FST format, which is painful to maintain when reading into thousands of CSV files. A "csv-based" solution would be even better.

**Methodology 3:** SQLite DB

```
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "NEW_DB")
dbWriteTable(db, "chocs", fread("myFile.csv"), append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM chocs WHERE V1 = 1 AND V2 = 1")
```

*The problem with this method is that it creates SQL DB whereas the CSV is already present, and the queries are not as fast as with the FST library proposed in methodology 2*

Is there any fast methodology ?

Comment: read.table() is from base R. fread() is from data.table.

Comment: With method 3, something like `dbGetQuery(db, "CREATE INDEX i1 ON chocs (V2, V1)")` after the data load and not creating the primary key index before bulk load (as noted by Panagiotis)

Comment: The primary key is an *index* that has to be updated for each row inserted. A common trick when loading data in bulk is to *disable* or delete indexes, load the data then rebuild them.

Comment: @MihaTrošt I amended the code, my bad.

Comment: @epi99 : i will try your idea. Is it the same as proposed by Panagiotis ?

Comment: @NielsouAkbrg SQLite can import CSV files directly with the `.import` command [as shown here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/). You can add the index/primary key afterwards

Comment: Have a look at http://www.fstpackage.org/

Comment: Did you try `fread("myFile.csv", skip = M, nrows = 1)` from the `data.table`-package?

Comment: @Jaap yes same generic issue with the skip=8M, it's as long as reading the whole file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I created my index afterwards on key1 and key2. Queries like "SELECT * FROM chocs WHERE V1 = 1 AND V2 = 1" are very fast now. Yet queries like "SELECT * FROM chocs WHERE V2 = 1" are taking quite longer (around 30sec). There is a maximum of 10k values with a given V2. Is there a way to improve my indexation ?

Comment: Do you need fast access to the same csv or do you need fast access to an arbitrary csv? In other words, is the overhead of a single read important or not?

Comment: @TimSalabim : many thanks for this package.

Answer (score 2):

`fst` is nice, as I see @TimSalabim mentioned in the comments , but you have to read it in first, then write it as a fst file. If you need to read arbitrary single lines multiple times in different sessions, then I would say it's reasonable to spend that 2 minutes reading it in one time as a data table with `fread` and then writing it out as a fst file.

The example with `iris`.

```
library(fst)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(iris)
write_fst(DT, "iris.fst")
x <- read_fst("iris.fst", from = 111, to = 111)
x
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1          6.5         3.2          5.1           2 virginica

# exit your session, come back tomorrow
library(fst)
x <- read_fst("iris.fst", from = 99, to = 99)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1          5.1         2.5            3         1.1 versicolor
```

For you, of course, you'd start with

```
DT<- fread("myFile.csv")
write_fst(DT, "myFile.fst")
x <- read_fst("myFile.fst", from = 1e7, to = 1e7)
```

I'm on a dinky machine right now with limited memory, so I'm not going to create a 2GB object and save it to test, but the iris example works and once you've spent the startup cost of creating the file, your line read should be substantially faster. Presumably you're on a decent machine with openMP support and an SSD.

Comment: I just finished testing this exact solution as proposed by @TimSalabim and it's doing wonders. It scales very nicely when the From = M reachs high figures ! Very impressing

Comment: @NielsouAkbrg glad you're finding `fts`helpful. I think it does a good job of being both easy to work with and very fast. if you feel this answers your question, please mark it as the answer. If you feel it's well researched and well explained, upvote it! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I updoted your post, yet a native solution would be even better. I will mark it as the answer by EOD if no better is found.

Answer (score 0):

how about `fread` from the `data.table` package? The row selection could look something like this:

```
dt[.(1,1), on = .(V1, V2)]
```

Comment: Yes, 2 GB is not large in this time and age. I'd simply `fread` the whole file as this answer suggests.

Comment: I did fread the whole file but it takes way too long (around 2min).